# accessing attributes with same name in parent classes from child class

Tags: python, class

```
class name_1:
    def __init__(self,name1):
        self.name1=name1
class name_2:
    def __init__(self,name1):
        self.name1=name1
class id(name_1,name_2):
    def __init__(self,no,name1,name2):
        self.no=no
        super().__init__()        
    def pid(self):
        print(self.no^2)
    def names(self):
        names=self.name_1.name1+self.name_2.name1
        return(names)
        
obj1=id(12,"dwayne","johnson")
print(obj1.names())
```

AttributeError: 'id' object has no attribute 'name_1'
how can i assign values to the parent class as dwayne and johnson and combine them into names variable in child class and print it
PS: iam a newbie in python

Comment: Dont use **id** - its a a builtin function - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/id-function-python/#:~:text=id()%20is%20an%20inbuilt%20function%20in%20Python.&text=As%20we%20can%20see%20the,the%20same%20id()%20value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `name1` and `name2` to the parent classes:

```
class Firstname:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.firstname = name


class Lastname:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.lastname = name


class Name(Firstname, Lastname):
    def __init__(self, no, name1, name2):
        self.no = no
        Firstname.__init__(self, name1)
        Lastname.__init__(self, name2)

    def pid(self):
        print(self.no ^ 2)

    def names(self):
        names = self.firstname + self.lastname
        return (names)


n = Name(12, "dwayne", "johnson")
print(n.names())
```

Out:

```
dwaynejohnson
```

**Edit**: Using `Firstname` and `Lastname` as attributes of `Name`, which comes closer to what you want:

```
class Firstname:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Lastname:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Name():
    def __init__(self, no, name1, name2):
        self.no = no
        self.firstname = Firstname(name1)
        self.lastname = Firstname(name2)

    def pid(self):
        print(self.no ^ 2)

    def names(self):
        names = self.firstname.name + self.lastname.name
        return (names)


n = Name(12, "dwayne", "johnson")
print(n.names())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what if both  the parent classes have an attribute called 'head' and you want to access head attribute of each parent class from child class

Comment: There will be just one attribute `head`, whose value gets overwritten.